# copy files from server to another with t-sql

Tags: sql, import, export, bcp

I'm in trouble. I need copy a file from one server to another using T-sql. The format is variable (pdf, xlsx, doc, jpg), but generally excel .xlsx.

For now my solution is to convert on the source server the file in a varbinary data and pass it as a parameter to a stored procedure located on the target server.

The code in the source server:

```
DECLARE @temp table(data varbinary (max))
DECLARE @out varbinary(max)

INSERT INTO @temp(data)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\original.xlsx', SINGLE_BLOB) as data

SELECT @out=data FROM @temp
EXEC DEST_SERVER.copy @out
```

(I am aware that the code is ugly and redundant, but so far going well)

The code on the destination server is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE copy @in varbinary(max)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE ##temp(data varbinary(max))
    insert into ##temp(data) values(@in)
    declare @SQLcommand varchar(1000)
    set @SQLcommand = 'bcp "SELECT data FROM ##temp" queryout "C:\copied.xlsx" -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -n'
    exec xp_cmdshell @SQLcommand
    DROP TABLE ##temp
END
```

By the time the procedure works to create the new file on the destination server, but both files are slightly different.

Specifically, the new file has a few more bits at the beginning, everything else is identical:

> **original.xlsx**
>
> 50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00
>
> 08 00 00 00 21 00 A7 95
>
> F9 99 84 01 00 00 14 06
>
> 00 00 13 00 DD 01 5B 43
>
> 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 5F 54
>
> etc...
>
> **copied.xlsx**
>
> 4F 32 00 00 00 00 00 00   -> this bytes are new
>
> 50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00
>
> 08 00 00 00 21 00 A7 95
>
> F9 99 84 01 00 00 14 06
>
> 00 00 13 00 DD 01 5B 43
>
> 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 5F 54
>
> etc...

What am I doing wrong ?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guy in this post had the same problem.
He fix it by specifying a format file with the bcp command.
I think this might be your problem too.
It looks like it might have something to do with bcp and a varbinary column.

[SQL Server BCP export corrupted file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301763/sql-server-bcp-export-corrupted-file)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to sidestep bcp, but with your help the problem was solved and I'll have to use it. Thanks again.

Comment: If that's the case, did you consider xp_cmdshell to simply do a file copy?