# Spaces in SQL column data...Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, binary-data, sqldatatypes

I am trying to do the following bulk insert:

```
BULK INSERT DATABASE.TABLE FROM 'C:\local\output\TESTFILE.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n').
```

Receiving the following error:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 2 (BinaryString).

Entire contents of TESTFILE.txt is as follows:

```
 /STR_8.YOU.Test ; 1C 48 D0 00
```

NOTE: When I remove the spaces between binary data, so it looks like

```
 /STR_8.YOU.Test ; 1C48D000
```

it works just fine.

My TABLE has the following 2 columns in it:

```
IDString      varchar(50)
BinaryString  varbinary(MAX)
```

Is there a particular data type to use to account for not only a binary string, but also the space character?  I have tried using all reasonable data types to include varchar(MAX), varbinary(MAX), image (replacement for BLOB?). Or is there a particular argument I need to use to allow for the space character?

Comment: You could import it to a staging table with a varchar(max) second column, remove the spaces and then import it to your destination table.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am not familiar with staging tables, but can you tell me a little more about how importing to a staging table would differ from importing to a destination table?  Is there a little more leniency on the data?  I guess I am just assuming the same issue in trying to use varchar with existing spaces would be encountered.  And similar to your suggestion, if all else fails I can simply manipulate the data prior to DB import to remove the spaces; was just hoping to not have to do this step.

Comment: A staging table is just a regular table, but its purpose is to temporarily hold data so you can cleanse it before moving it to the final destination.  I am assuming that the spaces in your data make it invalid for importing to a binary column, but it should be fine to import to a varchar.

Comment: With spaces in the data I have had no success in using any data type thus far to import the data, to include varchar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely grabbing at straws here,  but there seems to be an issue with bcp and binary columns. I remember reading somewhere that bulkinsert uses bcp in the background, so maybe this will work for you too.

The fix was to specify a format file for the import.

[SQL Server BCP export corrupted file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301763/sql-server-bcp-export-corrupted-file)

Hope that helps

Comment: Not too familiar with format files, but will look into and see if it will do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use bcp to generate the format file for you.