# Export images from a SQL Server using Stored procedures

Tags: sql, database, image, t-sql, export

I'm using Microsoft Sql server 2012 as DBMS, there I have my database which is containing informations about **football players**. Each player has a photography, and I need to export players photos to my computer, I guess it is possible to do it over TSQL, so I could avoid programming or editing my application to export photos only.

Here is what I  did so far:

[image]

MY SQL CODE:

> EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 GO RECONFIGURE GO EXEC
>   sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 GO RECONFIGURE GO
>
> EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'mkdir C:\ImagesFromSql'
>
> EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT Photo FROM
>   [FootballTeam].[dbo].[Players]" queryout
>   "C:\ImagesFromSql\TestImage.jpg" -T -N'

As you can see, my folder ImagesFromSql is created on "C:\", also one photo is stored there but intersting is that photo is 361MB big so probably that is size of all photos that are contained in database?
And I am wondering how could I export all images from database instead of one in this case, and is it possible to set their names for example lets set Image name as PlayerID, for example 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg....650.jpg...

after @H.Fadlallah suggested some answers this is what I get: [image]

It is impossible to preview image.. :)

Again after @H.Fadlallah help I executed this query:

> DECLARE @ID as int DECLARE @SQL as varchar(4000)
>
> DECLARE  csr CURSOR FOR SELECT PlayerID FROM
>   [FootballTeam].[dbo].[Players]
>
> OPEN csr
>
> FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @ID
>
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  BEGIN
>
> SET @SQL = 'BCP "SELECT Photo FROM [FootballTeam].[dbo].[Players] WHERE
>   PlayerID = "' + CAST(@ID as varchar(10)) + ' queryout
>   "C:\ImagesFromSql\' + CAST(@ID as varchar(10)) + '.jpg" -T -f
>   C:\ImagesFromSql\formatfile.fmt'
>
> EXEC master..xp_cmdshell  @SQL
>
> FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @ID
>
> END
>
> CLOSE csr DEALLOCATE csr

But Now I'm getting empty images, probably I missed something.. (btw file formatfile.fmt is created in same folders as images and I changed binary value for my Photo attribute from 8 to 0 as H.Fadallah suggested me in another post).

Comment: This is one very useful question, I hope so somebody will give you right answer! I need answer to this question also!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following query:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 

GO 
RECONFIGURE 
GO 
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE 
GO

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'mkdir C:\ImagesFromSql'


DECLARE @ID as int
DECLARE @SQL as varchar(4000)

DECLARE  csr  CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM [FootballTeam].[dbo].[Players]

OPEN csr

FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN


SET @SQL = 'BCP "SELECT Photo FROM [FootballTeam].[dbo].[Players] WHERE ID = "' + CAST(@ID as varchar(10)) + ' queryout "C:\ImagesFromSql\' + CAST(@ID as varchar(10)) + '.jpg" -T -N'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell  @SQL

FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @ID

END


CLOSE csr
DEALLOCATE csr
```

Comment: first line is giving me this error :  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: Next message: Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT'.

Comment: Fixed it again :-)  the syntax is     FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @ID

Comment: I will test it in a second, and what about if I have different types in database for example .jpg and .png this query will still download images but it will change extension of all images to .jpg?

Comment: I think your best bet is to dump the files in a directory, and then find some third-party tool that is able to identify files from the format alone.

Comment: check for edit of my post, looks like images are downloaded, but somehow I can not open them to see how they look like / preview..

Comment: What do you mean ? export files to directory with query you've posoted and after that to find some tool to indentify format?

Comment: Yes, that what i mean. because the it is recomanded to store file extension when it was inserted into sql.

Comment: Read this [Article](http://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data) it may help

Comment: ok bro, I will check for that article now! and do you know why the images can not be previewed / viewed when they are downloaded? check for edit of my post, there is a screenshot how that looks when I try to open image.

Comment: Maybe the extension is incorrect. try to change it manually to other image format

Comment: third party tool might help me to determine right extension of my image and  everything might be fine? I tried jpeg and .png and it did not worked.. probably its because it came from SQL

Comment: Read this [Article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301763/sql-server-bcp-export-corrupted-file) it may help

Comment: I created file from link you gave me, and set 8 to 0 and saved it, but could you help me reformat Query to execute it as I should? could you take a look at edit of my post, with current query I did, I am getting empty images, and I guess that is not right way, maybe I should skip adding extension? :/

Comment: Why not trying to do a workaroubd using a simple .net application

Comment: Try to load images into a datatable and it is easy to export them

Comment: Have a look [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file)

Comment: coud you take a look for my edit? Probably I did not format query correct, could you test it somewhere, I am really lost, and about .NET app, well I would like to avoid programming application for export, I need this only once :(

Comment: Look like BCP is not working fine with images try [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file) out

Comment: i tried but I am facing error I wrote in comment of that post, looks like I must write code to export images from sql :/ I really didnt want to touch appliation but looks like I must do it :/